# file too large for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, memory-management, out-of-memory, heap-memory

So... I was generating queries and then I pastes one particularly long one into eclipse, eclipse encountered a heap error and then crashed. I thought, no big deal, I can just go back in and delete a bunch, except for... every time I try to look at the file now eclipse will just crash. Either a heap error or a gc overhead limit error. I plan on just deleting this from outside eclipse, but I really want to know if there are any clever ways of attacking this problem. It's less than 14 megs, and I didn't really think that eclipse would have a problem with it, any insights on why?

Comment: is it just plain text? perhaps when it is opened in a specific editor, there is a lot of additional info (e.g. a dom structure for xml files). i guess this can take quite some time to generate for big files

Comment: well, it's just a bunch of insert statements, so I don't think there would be a lot of additional info. I might be wrong about that though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you are invoking a generic text editor. Either name the file with an extension of .txt, or make sure you don't have something like an SQL editor associated with the file type. (Check in Window | Preferences | General | Editors | File Associations). Another possibility is to right-click the file, choose Open With.., then choose 'Text Editor'.

Second, you might need to start Eclipse with a bit more JVM Heap, depending on what else is in the workspace. You do this by either adding command line arguments to your invocation (eclipse -vmargs -Xmx1000M), or editing your eclipse.ini. You can read more details at
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F

Comment: Is it possible to use a generic text editor within eclipse? I mean, I'm copying and pasting it from excel, so the ability to open that amount of information is not really an issue, but if I could change which text editor eclipse used I think it would be pretty cool. Also I already increased my heap size to 1GB and feel kinda uncomfortable putting it far above that.

Comment: If you click on the file, Eclipse decides on the editor, usually by the file extension. Java editor for .java files, JSP editor for .jsp files, etc. If you don't want that editor, you can right-click, and choose Open With. In that list, you should see 'Text Editor', which opens the file like it would be in Notepad. You can choose Open With | Other... to let Eclipse list all the editor types it knows about.

Comment: Another thought. You could 1) name your large file with an extension '.txt' 2) Right click and choose Open With | System Editor. That will launch Notepad (if you run Windows) instead of a built-in editor.

Comment: well, running this in an outside editor is not really helpful, but it is cool to know that eclipse allows me to use different editors within it.