# Load XMI file in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, xmi

I have XMI file that I'd like to open in Eclipse for the visual representation of the information inside. Right now my Eclipse hangs when I'm trying to open this file.

Is it possible to open XMI in Eclipse in order to see the visual representation of the information inside(not as XML)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

1. Go to Windows->Preferences->General->Editor-> File Associations .
2. Add a new `*.xmi` association and set the internal editor as you like.
3. Take care, that the correct editor is set as `default`.
4. Reopen the file. (eventually restart eclipse before)
5. Use the "Design/Source" bottom tab to switch between editor views.

Find [more info here](https://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-51.xhtml)

6. If the file is too large you might want to [follow the suggestions given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11630532/file-too-large-for-eclipse)